# AWS ECS service error: Task long arn format must be enabled for launching service tasks with ECS managed tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have a ECS service running in a cluster which has 1 task. Upon task update, the service suddenly died with error: 
`'service my_service_name failed to launch a task with (error Task long arn format must be enabled for launching service tasks with ECS managed tags.)'`

Current running tasks are automatically drained and the above message shows up every 6 hours in the "Events" tab of the service. Any changes done to the service config does not repair the issue. Rolling back the task update also doesn't change anything.

I believe I'm already using the long ARN format. Looking for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be a AWS bug acknowledged by them now. It was supposed to manifest after Jan 1 2020 but appeared early because of a workflow fault in AWS.

The resources were created by an IAM user who was later deleted and hence the issue appears.

Comment: Yeah, can verify this is what happened to me.

Comment: Got us too. We had to delete the service and recreate it with a new user with the ARN opt-in stuff applied to resolve it.

Comment: how do you opt in for user identity that has Programmatic access instead of console access?

Answer (score 2):

I simply removed the following from my task JSON input: propagateTags, enableECSManagedTags

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are Tagging Your Amazon ECS Resources but you did not opt-in to this feature so you have to opt-in and I thin you are using regular expression in deployment so if your deployment mechanism uses regular expressions to parse the old format ARNs or task IDs, this may be a breaking change.

> Starting today you can opt in to a new Amazon Resource Name (ARN) and
>   resource ID format for Amazon ECS tasks, container instances, and
>   services. The new format enables the enhanced ability to tag resources
>   in your cluster, as well as tracking the cost of services and tasks
>   running in your cluster.
>
> In most cases, you don’t need to change your system beyond opting in
>   to the new format. However, if your deployment mechanism uses regular
>   expressions to parse the old format ARNs or task IDs, this may be a
>   breaking change. It may also be a breaking change if you were storing
>   the old format ARNs and IDs in a fixed-width database field or data
>   structure.
>
> After you have opted in, any new ECS services or tasks have the new
>   ARN and ID format. Existing resources do not receive the new format.
>   If you decide to opt out, any new resources that you later create then
>   use the old format.

You can check this AWS compute blog to migrate to new ARN.

[migrating-your-amazon-ecs-deployment-to-the-new-arn-and-resource-id-format-2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/migrating-your-amazon-ecs-deployment-to-the-new-arn-and-resource-id-format-2/)

**Tagging Your Amazon ECS Resources**

> To help you manage your Amazon ECS tasks, services, task definitions,
>   clusters, and container instances, you can optionally assign your own
>   metadata to each resource in the form of tags. This topic describes
>   tags and shows you how to create them.
>
> **Important**
>
> To use this feature, it requires that you opt-in to the new Amazon
>   Resource Name (ARN) and resource identifier (ID) formats. For more
>   information, see [Amazon Resource Names (ARNs) and IDs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-account-settings.html#ecs-resource-ids).

[ecs-using-tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-using-tags.html)

Comment: Actually, Im not using this feature at all. I've found though that the IAM user who created this service is no longer a part of this AWS account. Does that make any diff?

Comment: You can check this article as i mentioned but I did not experienced this after deleting IAM user. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-using-tags.html